# RegEx match IP on Mail-Header Received:

Tags: regex

I try to fiddle a RegEx, which returns me only the Sender IP Address:

http://regexr.com?38atl

This is the RegEx I build, but cant complete:

```
(?<=\bReceived: from .*\[)(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}
```

or

```
(?<=\bReceived: from )(.*\[)(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}
```

So it should only match this (on lines beginning with: Received: from)

```
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
21.22.23.24
```

And this are a example Mail-Headers i'm search in:

```
To: a@domain.de
Return-Path: <t@domain.de>
X-Original-To: a@domain.de
Delivered-To: c@domain.tld
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
        by mail1.domain.tld (Postfix) with ESMTP id 3fT3TR72zNz8m8
        for <a@domain.de>; Tue, 18 Feb 2014 14:54:35 +0100 (CET)
X-Virus-Scanned: Debian amavisd-new at mail1.domain.tld
X-Spam-Flag: YES
X-Spam-Score: 5.773
X-Spam-Level: *****
X-Spam-Status: Yes, score=5.773 tagged_above=1 required=4.5
        tests=[BAYES_05=-0.5, MISSING_MID=0.497, RCVD_IN_PBL=3.335,
        RCVD_IN_RP_RNBL=1.31, RDNS_DYNAMIC=0.982, TO_NO_BRKTS_DYNIP=0.139,
        T_RCVD_IN_SEMBLACK=0.01] autolearn=no
Received: from mail1.domain.tld ([127.0.0.1])
        by localhost (mail1.domain.tld [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
        with ESMTP id lDJqiZjBn2t4 for <a@domain.de>;
        Tue, 18 Feb 2014 14:54:34 +0100 (CET)
Received: from mail.domain.tld (pAAAAAAAA.dip0.t-ipconnect.de [21.22.23.24])
        by mail1.domain.tld (Postfix) with SMTP id 3fT3TQ4Nwgz8m5
        for <a@domain.de>; Tue, 18 Feb 2014 14:54:34 +0100 (CET)
Date: Tue, 18 Feb 2014 15:02:11 +0100
Sender: "From" <t@domain.de>
From: "From" <t@domain.de>
Subject: Subbbb (192.168.123.123)
Reply-To: t@domain.de
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Message-Id: <3fT3TR72zNz8m8@mail1.domain.tld>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this expression:

```
Received: +from[^\n]*?\[([0-9\.]+)\]
```

Edit:

For a PHP script try something like this (where $emailHeader contains the data you are searching):

```
$regex = '/Received: +from[^\\n]*?\\[([0-9\\.]+)\\]/s';
if  (preg_match_all($regex, $emailHeader, $matches_out)) {
  print_r($matches_out);
} else {
  print('Sender IP not found');
}
```

Comment: it matches the full line: http://regexr.com?38atc | I updated my question with the url for the regexr.com

Comment: Are you not able to utilise capture groups? Where would you be using this expression?

Comment: I dont know what u mean with capture groups. I wanna use it to retrieve the IP Address of the sender in a PHP Script.

Comment: I've updated my answer. In the future you'll probably get a much better response volume and a more specific answer if you include the programming language you are using in the question or as tags to the question.

Comment: thanks, it works :) - but don't understand why it is different result in regexr.com

Answer (score 0):

The <= in the star looks funny, but other than that it seems to be working fine:

```
(?:\bReceived: from .*\[)((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(?:]\))
```

Comment: The `<=` group is known as a positive look behind. It will evaluate the match inside without consuming any characters as part of the subsequent expression. He was doing this presumably because he can only output the entire regex match i.e. `match[0]` and didn't want to include anything other than the IP address.

Comment: the <= means: Positive lookbehind. Matches a group before your main expression without including it in the result. - I only whant the IP Adresses on Lines which beginn with "Received: from "

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is:

```
(?:\bReceived: from .*?\[)(?<ip>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})
```

the matched IP address will be in capture group named "ip".